# R: Randomly shuffle the contents of all columns that have a specific column name

Tags: r

In below R dataframe I would like to randomly shuffle the contents of all columns whose names start with 'b' (while preserving column names and position):

```
> df1
  a1 a2 b1 b2
1  1  4 50 55
2  1  4 60 65
3  0  4 70 75
4  0  4 80 85
```

So one result may be:

```
> df1
  a1 a2 b1 b2
1  1  4 55 50
2  1  4 60 65
3  0  4 75 70
4  0  4 85 80
```

Answer (score 1):

Does this work:

```
cbind(df[!grepl('b',colnames(df))], sapply(df[grep('b',colnames(df))], function(x) sample(x, length(x))))
  a1 a2 b1 b2
1  1  4 80 55
2  1  4 70 85
3  0  4 50 75
4  0  4 60 65
```

Comment: Your code works, but randomized columns get appended to the end of the table, woulb be good if they keep their position.

Comment: @Madamadam, I think you can do that by entering the correct columns in the `cbind` function. Like `cbind(df[grep('a',colnames(df))],sapply(df[grep('b',colnames(df))], function(x) sample(x, length(x))), df[grep('c',colnames(df))`.

Answer (score 1):

Tidyverse solution

```r
library(tidyverse)

df_example <- read_table('a1 a2 b1 b2
 1  4 50 55
  1  4 60 65
  0  4 70 75
 0  4 80 85')

df_example |> 
  mutate(across(starts_with('b'),.fns = ~ sample(.x,length(.x))))
#> # A tibble: 4 x 4
#>      a1    a2    b1    b2
#>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1     1     4    60    65
#> 2     1     4    50    75
#> 3     0     4    80    85
#> 4     0     4    70    55
```

<sup>Created on 2021-12-10 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: I tried your code with a large dataframe, in which every value occurs only once per row (but multiple times across rows), buth now identical values appear on one row! This may occur because rows get shuffled as well, or by any other cumbersome thing!

Comment: Sorry I don't understand what you mean, the rows are not part of the solution, the sort happens colwise without replacement, maybe I didn't understand what you needed

Answer (score 1):

```
df1 <- data.frame(a1 = c(1, 1, 0, 0), 
              a2 = rep(4, 4), 
              b1 = c(50, 60, 70, 80), 
              b2 = c(55, 65, 75, 85))

col_names <- names(df1)

df1 <- cbind(df1[, grep('a', names(df1))], 
             t(apply(df1[, grep('b', names(df1))], 1, function(x) {
               x <- rev(x)
               return(x)
               }))
)

names(df1) <- col_names

  a1 a2 b1 b2
1  1  4 55 50
2  1  4 65 60
3  0  4 75 70
4  0  4 85 80
```

Answer (score 1):

Yet another solution:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- data.frame(
  a1 = c(1L, 1L, 0L, 0L),
  a2 = c(4L, 4L, 4L, 4L),
  b1 = c(50L, 60L, 70L, 80L),
  b2 = c(55L, 65L, 75L, 85L)
)

set.seed(143)

df %>% 
  rowwise %>% 
  mutate(b = across(starts_with("b")) %>% list %>% 
           map(~ unlist(.x, use.names = F) %>% sample)) %>% 
  select(!matches("b\\d+")) %>% 
  unnest_wider(b, names_sep = "")

#> # A tibble: 4 × 4
#>      a1    a2    b1    b2
#>   <int> <int> <int> <int>
#> 1     1     4    55    50
#> 2     1     4    65    60
#> 3     0     4    70    75
#> 4     0     4    85    80
```